# Error (use-package): Cannot load ruby-test-mode

Tags: spacemacs, ruby

Installed `Spacemacs` and opened a `ruby` file. It got this error:

```
Error (use-package): Cannot load ruby-test-mode
```

I have researched on this issue: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/commit/91b8731b87ce888c8355b8aabcca368e423ac149

But didn't get idea for fixing it.

Comment: The package seems to be available from `melpa`. Do you have `melpa` in your `package-archives`? Do `C-h v package-archives RET` to find out.

Comment: After I restart `Spacemacs` with installed `ruby` in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` of `~/.spacemacs`, it didn't show that error again.